# Python Generate a Dynamic Nested dictionary from the list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list as given below:

```
dict = {'candidate1':{'preference1':0,'preference2':0,'preference3':0,'preference4':0},
            'candidate2':{'preference1':0,'preference2':0,'preference3':0,'preference4':0},
            'candidate3':{'preference1':0,'preference2':0,'preference3':0,'preference4':0},
            'candidate4':{'preference1':0,'preference2':0,'preference3':0,'preference4':0}
        .
        .
        . 
        }
```

How do I create a dynamic nested dictionary, that takes input in the form of list and create a dictionary in the above form?

```
lst = ['user1','user2','user3']
```

candidate will get replaced with the names in lst.
Thankyou

Comment: what is your desired output, example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
lst = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
d = {x: {'preference' + str(i): 0 for i in range(1,5)} for x in lst}
```

results in

```
d = {'user1': {'preference1': 0, 'preference2': 0, 'preference3': 0, 'preference4': 0},
     'user2': {'preference1': 0, 'preference2': 0, 'preference3': 0, 'preference4': 0},
     'user3': {'preference1': 0, 'preference2': 0, 'preference3': 0, 'preference4': 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: I have a question, I am trying to access this from another class,
but the value is not showing

Comment: class name:

    d = {}

    list = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

    def load(self):

        self.gsuofficerdict = {x: {'preference' + str(i): 0 for i in range(1,5)} for x in self.list}
        
class test(name):
    print(name.d)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
{k: {'preference1': 0, 'preference2': 0, 'preference3': 0, 'preference4': 0} for k in lst}
```